# How To Mock/Stub a Nhibernate QueryOver Call?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mocking, rhino-mocks

How can I stub a call that returns a QueryOver object that contains data?

```
        public interface IData
        {
            IQueryable<Customer> CustomersAsQueryable { get; }
            IQueryOver<Customer> CustomersAsQueryOver { get; } 
        }

        [Fact]
        public void QueryOver_spike()
        {
            var customers = new List<Customer>
                                {
                                    new Customer {Name = "this"},
                                    new Customer {Name = "is"},
                                    new Customer {Name = "fubar"}
                                };         

            var data = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IData>();

            //this works
            data.Stub(x => x.CustomersAsQueryable).Return(customers.AsQueryable());

            //how can i stub this?
            data.Stub(x => x.CustomersAsQueryOver).Return(?????????);
        }
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother, I would just use SQLite as an in-memory database that lives for the duration of that unit test.

Comment: @phill, that's not a unit test.  that's an integration test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just like  Phill said sqlite would be easier. nevertheless this should work

```
var queryover = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IQueryOver<Customer>>();
queryover.Stub(...).Return(...);

data.Stub(x => x.CustomersAsQueryOver).Return(queryover);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that approach has been deprecated.

Comment: @krillgar which approach? Mocking the IQueryOver?

Comment: `MockRepository` no longer has any static methods on it. I checked the source on GitHub, and it's a blank class. The base is being removed in version 5.